# Show hidden div, why code works in FF/Chrome but NOT in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.hide
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<button style="width:200;height:20;background-color:#B4CFEC;font: bold 10px Verdana" onclick="document.getElementById('CUST_CLASS').classList.remove('hide');" >CUSTOMER DIMENSION</button>
<div class="hide" id="CUST_CLASS">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class'); function here.
Should I use a different function? Something Microsoft only?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support `classList`, but you can shim it.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: shim what.....?

Comment: Shim `classList`. Just Google `"classList shim"` and you should find some projects. Like this: https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/classList.js

Comment: Most people would use jQuery to do this. It handles browser compatibility for you, and provides a productive API to do dynamic HTML and interactivity.

Comment: Unless you're still supporting JavaScript in IE6/7, it's time to drop jQuery and start becoming comfortable with the native API.

Answer (score -1):

This is hideous, but removes the specified class, retaining all others:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('CUST_CLASS').setAttribute('class', document.getElementById('CUST_CLASS').getAttribute('class').replace('hide', ''));"
```

As commented, IE9 doesn't support `classList`, so you can either shim it, or fall back to jQuery, which would handle browser compatibility. This is the jQuery equivalent to your code:

```
$("#CUST_CLASS").removeClass("hide");
```

However, if your `hide` class is used for nothing more than toggling visibility, you could simplify even more:

```
$("#CUST_CLASS").hide();
$("#CUST_CLASS").show();
```